# How to rewrite Entity Framework query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, loops, entity-framework

I have a table called `passenger policy` that looks like this:

```
    public Guid HotelId { get; set; }
    
    public int FromAge { get; set; }
    public int ToAge { get; set; }
    public PassengerType PassengerType { get; set; }
```

and it has 3 rows for each `HotelId` key.

I have another table called `search` that looks like this

```
 public class Search : BaseEntity
 {
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }

     public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
     public Guid ProvinceId { get; set; }
     public Guid CityId { get; set; }
     public Guid HotelId { get; set; }
     public Guid VendorHotelRoomId { get; set; }
     public int StandardCapacity { get; set; }
     public int ExtraCapacity { get; set; }

     public int MaxInfantAge { get; set; }
     public int MaxChild1Age { get; set; }
     public int MaxChild2Age { get; set; }

     public double BasePrice { get; set; }
     public double ExtraAdultPrice { get; set; }
     public double ExtraInfantPrice { get; set; }
     public double ExtraChild1Price { get; set; }
     public double ExtraChild2Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a query in T-SQL (SQL Server) to get hotels based on date field, standard capacity and extra capacity.

The extra capacity has 3 possible values:

1. infant
2. child 1
3. child 2

- (fetched from passenger type table)

I write it like this in EF Core

```
var searchOnAllVendors hotelContext.Search
                                   .Where(c => c.Date >= fromDate 
                                               && c.Date <= toDate 
                                               && c.CityId == cityId
                                               && c.ExtraCapacity >= adultCount)
                                   .AsEnumerable();

foreach (var item in searchOnAllVendors)
{
    foreach (var ag in request.Passengers.ChildrensAges)
    {
        if (ag <= item.MaxInfantAge && ag < item.MaxChild1Age && ag < item.MaxChild2Age)
            infant++;

        if (ag > item.MaxInfantAge && ag <= item.MaxChild1Age)
            child1Count++;

        if (ag > item.MaxChild1Age && ag <= item.MaxChild2Age)
            child2Count++; 
                    
        if (ag > item.MaxChild1Age && ag <= item.MaxChild2Age)
            extraAdult++;
    }

    if (item.MaxInfantAge >= infant && item.MaxChild1Age >= child1Count && item.MaxChild2Age >= child2Count)
    {
        var adulPrice = extraAdult * item.ExtraAdultPrice;
        var infantPrice = infant * item.ExtraInfantPrice;
        var child1Price = child1Count * item.ExtraChild1Price;
        var child2Price = child1Count * item.ExtraChild2Price;

        var finalPrice = adulPrice + infantPrice + child1Price + child2Price + item.BasePrice;

        searches.Add(new Search_Response
                         {
                             CityId = item.CityId,
                             CountryId = item.CountryId,
                             HotelId = item.HotelId,
                             ProvinceId = item.ProvinceId,
                             VendorHotelRoomId = item.VendorHotelRoomId,
                             Price = finalPrice
                         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: convert it to T-SQl

Comment: So update your question with your attempt to convert it to T-SQL and explain what specific issue you are having with it i.e. don’t just say that “it doesn’t work”. If it errors then what is the error message; if it gives the wrong result then what result does it give and what result were you expecting

Comment: i want to use two loop ( for each ) in my code as i explained above

Comment: Hi - unfortunately this is not a site where you are likely to find someone who will do this for you, it’s not a free coding site. You need to show you have made some effort to solve the problem yourself and then ask a question about a specific issue you are facing

Comment: plus your example has a couple bugs:  child2Price is using child1Count., and your extraAddult  and child2Count increment conditions are the same.  I'm guessing the extaAdult should be: `if (ag > item.MaxChild2Age ) extraAdult++;`

As for doing all of that in TSQL, no idea. Other options if you are running into performance issues would be to fetch just the data about each item you need using `Select` rather than loading all fields from the vendors. The age group counts could be calculated without iterating.  Other than that, the question would be "why" do you want to do this in TSQL?

Comment: @StevePy thank you for your help yes i fix that ,  i want to do  that for performance and it works perfectly file 
in Ef Core I take 12Second to Render data but in T-SQL it reduce to 900ms

Comment: @NickW sometimes we do not need exact code we need just a push or help to run Sometimes we can help without pay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after couple days and try a few things i find a way to have best performance in T-SQL
...
1. Get count of extra passernger types in scalar-valued functions like  this :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetChildRule](@ages as nvarchar(max),@min as int,@max as int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
declare @count int

select @count=count(*) from STRING_SPLIT(@ages,',')
where value > @min and value <= @max
RETURN @count
END
```

...

and use it in stored procedure  like a field as below :

```
select * , GetChildRule('1,2,3',mymin,mymax) from Search where date between date1 and date2
```

and call it in EF CORE:

```
Context.Set<YourModelWithAllOfFiledYouReturnInSP>()
.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC  [dbo].[StaySearch] @extraAges = N'{ages}', 
@checkInDate = N'{fromDate}', @checkOutDate = N'{toDate}',
@destinationId = '{destinationId}',
@countrySearch = '{countrysearch}',@adultCount={adultCount}");
```